# Is there a security issue with letting users check for username availability

Tags: authentication, security, user-input

When a user signs up for our website, we check if the username is already in use. Our requirements document says that we should check for the username availability as the username is being typed on the signup form. As long as the username is already present in our database, we should disable all the other fields (password, email etc.). Then we should enable the other fields only if the username is unique and meets other criteria.

What are the security implications of this approach?

Comment: It's called "user(name) enumeration". Whether it counts as a vulnerability is debated, the impact depends a lot on the type of service you are running. (On many websites, usernames are public anyway). After a risk assessment, you'll need to trade-off security against usability.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124653/why-do-several-bug-bounties-ignore-user-enumeration, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47679/how-to-prevent-email-discovery-in-forms, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62661/generic-error-message-for-wrong-password-or-username-is-this-really-helpful and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69370/preventing-user-enumeration-on-registration-page

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [security.SE] - they have [a whole tag on *user-enumeration*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-enumeration?tab=Votes)

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I will research on security stack exchange. Feel free to close this question here.